# Debian installation is emergency mode, how to recover data and create a new installation with previous installation's apps and data?

Tags: debian, backup, data-recovery, corruption

I'm using a Raspberry Pi as a home media server, and it has been in emergency mode for a while. Despite being in this mode, it continues to function normally.

My question is, is there an effective way to back up all the necessary data? My main concern is the extensive configuration I have done, which has taken a significant amount of time to create a perfect environment for a media server.

This includes setting up automatic mounting of specific drives at boot, configuring daemons to avoid the need for foreground software execution (particularly since this is a command-line interface), and installing various packages and applications to ensure smooth operation.

If it's possible to fix the current installation, I am open to that option, but reinstalling appears to be the simplest approach.

Does anyone have a recommended plan of action in this situation?

Comment: The first step would be to understand *why* the system is in emergency mode, as it may affect what backup/recovery strategies are available. It might be something as simple as a mistyped `/etc/fstab` line making the system think it needs to mount something that isn't available. Unless `/etc/fstab` lines are configured with a `noauto` or `nofail` mount option, they are treated as absolute requirements at boot time, and if the system cannot satisfy even one line without such an option, the system will drop into emergency mode.

Comment: @telcoM DAMN. my system wasn't corrupted ig. thanks! i only ever saw that message when i hooked it up to a monitor (which was rare since it was for a server) and when it's plugged into the monitor it's usually unplugged from the drive which it's usually plugged into.

Comment: There is usually a way to review the boot-time messages afterwards; on a modern Debian, `journalctl --list-boots` will tell you if there are logs from previous boots available, and `journalctl -xb` should show the messages from the current boot (add a boot ID to see logs of other boots). The messages are displayed using `less` by default, so you will be able to use the arrow keys to scroll forward/backward and also to right/left if there are lines longer than your current terminal window.